# Using Sitecore PowerShell Extension with native PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, sitecore

Is it possible to use [Sitecore PowerShell Extension](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) without installing Sitecore with the PowerShell that is included when you install windows.

In particular, I would like to use the `Show-ListView` cmdlet that comes with the Sitecore PowerShell Extension that lets you create beautiful reports as shown [here](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/25/creating-beautiful-sitecore-reports-easily-with-powershell-extensions/) and Export contents of the view in XML, CSV, JSON, HTML or Excel file will taking into account current filter and order of the items.

[image: Show-]

Comment: @Ian Graham - actually SPE runs using Windows Powershell, in fact if you don't have the right version of Powershell, some commands do not work at all. See https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/installation.html for the Prerequisites for SPE.

Comment: Thanks, Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

The Sitecore PowerShell Extensions module is based upon a provider built in C# that interfaces with Sitecore through its API and has dependencies on the Windows PowerShell libraries. As noted by Richard, you'll need to make sure at minimum Windows PowerShell 3 (as right now) is installed on the server hosting Sitecore.

Comment: What I would like to know is can you use the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions on a personal windows computer that does not have the SiteCore installed

Comment: You can use the Windows PowerShell module that we include called SPE Remoting. We have examples in the book to connect to Sitecore ( with SPE installed) remotely. Under the covers it calls a web service.

Comment: Remoting section https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/remoting.html